# Folder action scaffold

Tags: finder, automator, folders, folder-action

I'm a graphic designer and need an organized folder scaffold for all of my projects. I have a work flow now that:

- asks for the project name
- asks where the project folder needs to be stored
- then creates the sub folders that I will be using.

Such as a folder named "Project 1" then inside are the sub folders named "images", "Photoshop", "drafts", "Illustrator" and so on.

[image: Scaffold][image]

I am trying to create a folder action that sorts files that are added to the project root folder into the an appropriate sub folder, either by file extension or by part fo the file names.

For example:

- `.jpg` files shoudl be moved to the image folder
- `.psd` files should be moved to the Photoshop folder
- file names that contain the word "draft" should be moved to the drafts folder.

What I've tried so far is to make a folder action that does this but it sends those files to the folder originally writen in the folder action. If I make a folder action that sends `.psd` files to the Photoshop folder into "Project 1", then that action to the next folder "Project 2" will still send those files to the Photoshop folder in "Project 1", instead of in "Project 2".

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: I don't have an answer on how to write the folder action such that it dynamically chooses the right root folder (Project 1, Project 2, etc...). However, I remembered [Post Haste](https://www.digitalrebellion.com/posthaste/), which might be handy for you as well. Also this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15831913/1256347) might be helpful.

Comment: For an Automator folder action, you need to specify the watched folder when saving the workflow.  An AppleScript folder action is a little more flexible, in that you can use the same script and specify the folder via the `Folder Actions Setup` service.  Either way, you will need to specify a folder action for each watched folder.

Comment: JSYK... The **Run Shell Script** _action_ shown in the screenshot exhibits a needless over use of the `mkdir` _command_ and actually only needs to be executed twice, e.g. `mkdir "$1/$2"; cd "$1/$2" || exit; mkdir 'After Effects' 'Assets' 'Audition' 'Drafts' 'Excel' 'Final' 'Fonts' 'Illustrator' 'Images' 'Photoshop' 'Premier' 'Word'` -- Note that the _single-quotes_ used in the second `mkdir` _command_ are only necessary for 'After Effects', however, my coding style is typically to quote all _strings_ for safety and/or visual clarity as appropriate.

Comment: Also, the screenshot in your OP excludes important information that's normally visible, e.g., what type of **Automator** _workflow_ it is, whether or not you've made the logical disconnect between certain _actions_, etc. Please adjust the size of the **Automator** _workflow_ to include that without being overly large. That said, is the screenshot actually your **Folder Action** or just the _workflow_ to create the _hierarchical folder structure_? **If you had also, included the exact specifications of what goes where, I would have posted a working solution as an answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is *a* way to go about achieving the goal. (It is not the only way to achieve the goal.)

First I'd make a *placeholder template* **Folder Action** using **Automator** and after creating it, disable it in **Folder Action Setup**, but leave the *workflow* available where it gets saved. This will be opened at the end of creating a *new project folder* to then be assigned to it and saved as its name, thus leaving the placeholder template **Folder Action** available for the next *new project folder*.

The images of the two *workflows* are placed at the bottom so as to make the answer easier to read.

You will need to add to the *example* **shell script** *code*, as all of the conditions were not expressed in your question.

---

### Placeholder template **Folder Action**

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

    # f = fully qualified pathname
    # d = directory pathname
    # fn = filename with extension
    # n = filename without extension
    # e = filename extension

shopt -s nocasematch

for f in "$@"; do

    d="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    # n="${fn%.*}"
    e="${fn##*.}"

    cd "${d}" || exit
    [ -w "${d}" ] || exit

    [[ ${e} == jpg ]] && mv -n "${f}" './Images/'
    [[ ${e} == psd ]] && mv -n "${f}" './Photoshop/'
    [[ ${fn} =~ draft ]] && mv -n "${f}" './Drafts/'

    [ -f "${f}" ] && mkdir -p 'Other'; mv -n "${f}" './Other/'

 done
```

**Note:** The last *test* before `done` handles any *case* not already defined. Obviously you can choose not to use it and remove it from the *example* **shell script** *code*.

---

### **Create New Project Folder Structure**

For an **Automator** *workflow* to create the *new project folder*, use the screenshot of the following *workflow*:

The *example* **shell script** *code* of the **Run Shell Script** *action* is:

```bash
mkdir "$1/$2" || exit
cd "$1/$2" || exit
mkdir 'After Effects' 'Assets' 'Audition' 'Drafts' 'Excel' 'Final' 'Fonts' 'Illustrator' 'Images' 'Photoshop' 'Premier' 'Word'

open "${HOME}/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/Foobar.workflow"
```

**Note:** Change the name of the **Folder Action** *workflow* in the *example* **shell script** *code* from **Foobar.workflow** to whatever its actual *name* is.

Also note in the image below of the **Create New Project Folder Structure** *workflow* how there are logical breaks between some of the *actions* and in the end the *value* of the two *variables* are separate from the rest of the *workflow*. While the *workflow* shown in the question works, nonetheless, in my opinion this is a better way of doing it as it breaks the *workflow* into *logical action blocks*, which makes it easier to follow/understand what the *workflow* is doing.

Technically the **Create New Project Folder Structure** *workflow* only needs one *variable* and it could be structured as, e.g:

- **Ask For Text** *action*
- **set Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable: [New Project]**
- **Ask for Finder Items** *action*

  - **[Optons] [√] Ignore this action's input**
- **Get Value of Variable** *action*

  - **Variable: [New Project]**
- **Run Shell Script** *action*

While this does work and has less *actions* than what's show in the question, nonetheless, as I mentioned earlier about *logical action blocks* within the *workflow* which makes it easier to follow/understand what the *workflow* is doing.

---

### Folder Action Setup

**Folder Action Setup** can be used to work with as needed any **Folder Action** created.

**Folder Action Setup** can be opened using **Spotlight** by pressing **⌘ Space** and start typing its name, then once selected, press **Enter**.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **different approach which does not use Automator.**

This following **AppleScript** code, in short, prompts you to choose a name for your new **Art Project** and where to create the Project and its directories.

After the Project’s directories structure has been created, a new **Folder Action** will then be **automatically created, saved, and attached to your new Project folder**.

The only thing that really needs to be done is to edit some of the values in the *script object* `script artProjectsFileProcessor`. This is the part of the code which tells the **Folder Action** what to do with the files that get added to the Project folder. *I added a few `conditional statements` to get you started on the right track.*

---

```
global createProject, projectName, newProjectFolderLocation, artProjectsFileProcessor

property pathToFolderActions : ((path to scripts folder as text) & "Folder Action Scripts:")
property artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction : "Art Projects Files Processor.scpt"
property subFolderNames : "After Effects
    Assets
    Audition
    Drafts
    Excel
    Final
    Fonts
    Illustrator
    Images
    Photoshop
    Premiere
    Word"

tell application "System Events" to set folderActionExists to exists of ¬
    alias (pathToFolderActions & artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction)

--if not folderActionExists then
store script artProjectsFileProcessor in ¬
    pathToFolderActions & artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction replacing yes
--end if

activate
set newProjectFolderLocation to POSIX path of ¬
    (choose folder with prompt "Choose A Location To Create Yor New Project Directory")

tell application "System Events"
    set existingFolders to name of folders of folder newProjectFolderLocation
end tell

set projectName to createProject()

if projectName is in existingFolders then
    repeat while projectName is in existingFolders
        display dialog "A project with that name already exists." & linefeed & ¬
            "Please choose a different name for your new project" buttons ¬
            {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
        set projectName to createProject()
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end if

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of subFolderNames & " | xargs -I {} mkdir -p " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of newProjectFolderLocation & quoted form of projectName & "/{}"

attachFolderActionToFolder(projectName, newProjectFolderLocation, artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction)

tell application "System Events"
    if not folder actions enabled then set folder actions enabled to true
end tell

set alertChoice to button returned of (display alert ¬
    "Art Project Created" message "Your new art project " & projectName & ¬
    " has been created in the directory... " & ¬
    newProjectFolderLocation & linefeed & linefeed & ¬
    "Folder Actions for this project are enabled and files are ready to be processed." buttons ¬
    {"Show In Finder", "OK"} default button 2 giving up after 20)

if alertChoice = "Show In Finder" then
    do shell script "open -R " & quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
        newProjectFolderLocation & quoted form of projectName
end if

on createProject()
    activate
    set projectName to text returned of ¬
        (display dialog "Entering a new project name will create a project folder with all necessary sub-folders" & ¬
            linefeed & linefeed & "After your project directories structure has been created,
 a new folder action will be created and automatically attached to your new project folder.
 It will then be ready to process any files added to it" default answer ¬
            "My New Project" buttons {"Cancel", "Create My Project"} ¬
            default button 2 cancel button 1 with title "New Project Creation")
    return projectName
end createProject

to attachFolderActionToFolder(projectName, newProjectFolderLocation, artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction)
    tell application "Folder Actions Setup"
        launch
        delay 1
        try
            set addedFolderAction to make new folder action with properties ¬
                {name:projectName, path:(newProjectFolderLocation & projectName)}
        end try
        try
            delay 0.5
            tell addedFolderAction to make new script with properties ¬
                {name:artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction, path:(pathToFolderActions & artProjectsFileProcessorFolderAction)}
        end try
    end tell
    delay 1
    tell application "Folder Actions Setup" to quit
end attachFolderActionToFolder

script artProjectsFileProcessor
    property afterEffectsFiles : {}
    property assetsFiles : {}
    property auditionFiles : {}
    property draftsFiles : "Draft"
    property excelFiles : {"xls"}
    property finalFiles : {}
    property fontsFiles : {"ttf"}
    property illustratorFiles : {"ai", "eps"}
    property imagesFiles : {"png", "jpg", "bmp"}
    property photoshopFiles : {"psd"}
    property premierFiles : {}
    property wordFiles : {"doc", "txt"}
    
    on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
        repeat with thisItem in theNewItems
            tell application "System Events"
                set nameExtension to name extension of thisItem
                set theName to name of thisItem
                if theName contains draftsFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Drafts" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in afterEffectsFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "After Effects" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in assetsFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Assets" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in auditionFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Audition" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in excelFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Excel" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in finalFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Final" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in fontsFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Fonts" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in illustratorFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Illustrator" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in imagesFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Images" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in photoshopFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Photoshop" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in premierFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Premier" of theFolder
                else if nameExtension is in wordFiles then
                    move thisItem to folder "Word" of theFolder
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end adding folder items to
end script
```

---

I saved this code as ”Art Project Creator.scpt” to my /Users/*MYSHORTNAME*/Library/Scripts/Applications/Finder … folder. Doing this allows me to run .scpt files directly from the Script Menu in the menu bar, when Finder is the active app.

This code could also be saved as an **Application** file and will run every time it is double clicked in Finder. Another option could be to create a new **Automator Quick Action**, and insert this code into a “**Run AppleScript**” command to the Workflow, allowing the code to run via the **Quick Actions Contextual Menu** in Finder.

[image]

---

This first animation demonstrates the creation of a new Art Project with its sub-directories.(Remember a new Folder Action will be automatically created, saved, and attached to your new Project folder.)

[image]

---

This second animation demonstrates adding files to the new Project Folder and the results of files’ new locations, processed from the code in its newly attached **Folder Action**

[image]

Comment: RE: "_Because of the time it is now, I will fine-tune the code and add some descriptive comments tomorrow._" -- This is a good start and I'm interested to see what else you add. That said, I'd like to make a couple of suggestions. 1. With `property pathToFolderActions` the `path to workflows folder` is normally used for **Automator** created **Folder Action**. The path for **AppleScript** _.scpt_ based **Folder Actions** is **~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts**, for which you can use `property pathToFolderActions : ((path to scripts folder as text) & "Folder Action Scripts:")` instead.

Comment: 2. The `tell application "Finder" to set folderActionExists to exists …` should really use **System Events**, as it incurs less overhead and **Finder** should be avoided in favor of **System Events** wherever applicable. 3. This one is the most glaring issue, sorry… The use of _Capital Case_ messages are much harder to read, goes agains the industry standard, and certainly not done by first rate developers. That's not to say never use _Capital Case_ as in some circumstance, albeit very few, it may lend itself appropriate, e.g., as the _title_ to a message.

Comment: Also, please, do not use _Capital Case_ in the code comments for the same reasons.  -- As I started writing this before your last update I'm leaving the now deleted quoted portion of my first comment.

Comment: Since nobody else wants to comment or acknowledge my brilliant usage of the very seldom used `store script` command for the process of creating and activating a `Folder Action`, I have no choice but to give myself an honorary +1

Answer (score -1):

My approach:

Since you already have a lot of files, I assume they are inside a root folder.
A folder quick action can:

1. Rename it with the requested text.
2. Store the path in a variable so you can search and move files inside it.
3. Duplicate a template from somewhere else in your HD with all the possible folders pre-arranjed and copy them to the path.
4. After the folder structure for your given project is ready, **search for filetype X. Search for folder X. Move filetype X to folder X.** Repeat for filetype Y. Etc. *If you search inside the path, you wont mess with other projects.*
5. At the end, look for empty folders and delete them, so you will only
   get the folders you need.